# How to deploy node.js app to cloud server

Tags: node.js, deployment, express

I want to automate my deployment of my node.js app from my machine to the cloud server?

It currently using expressjs.

Is there anything out there like this. Have tried googling but no luck

Cheers

Comment: You didn't mention you cloud provider, so I will assume it is a 'generic' IaaS provider more than a specific PaaS one. Many people automate this via their VCS tool, most often Github. You can simply clone your project on the remote machine, use npm to install the needed modules (which you oughtn't keep in VCS, but just record in your `package.json`) and you are good to go. Throw the steps in a script and you can trigger it remotely, via a cron to (e.g.) check for new code every day at 2AM, etc. Search S.O. or Bing around, and you'll find more elaboration on these approaches.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you need a private registry server. For example, [this one](https://github.com/rlidwka/sinopia), since it's easiest to install. You'll publish your node.js app there, so cloud servers will download it.

Secondly, you need to execute `npm update` on all your servers whenever you publish something there.

So my usual deployment process is this:

1. run `npm publish --reg http://my.private.registry:4873/` on local package
2. run `npm update --reg http://my.private.registry:4873/` on each of the remote servers (this can be automated using `puppet`)
3. restart all instances on each of the remote servers (`pm2 restart all` in my case, but you can use different supervisor)

PS: 2 and 3 steps can even be automatic when [this](https://github.com/rlidwka/sinopia/issues/6) gets implemented, so it'll just be `npm publish`

Comment: Can you please add some info about **supervisors**? Why pm2 and what alternatives are there (forever, upstart, etc.), and do you really need alternatives?

Comment: I use pm2 because of its built-in clustering. No idea what other people use.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this is what you're asking for, but companies like Heroku allow for automated deployment of apps from the desktop to the cloud. No relation, just a (free) customer.

Dave Winer has put together a very nicely documented how-to on this very subject:

http://scripting.com/2014/02/06/herokuForPoetsBeta.html